# Undefined array key in php file, POST request from AJAX call in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a small project in which I have to fetch some weather information when a user clicks on a button.

For some reason my $_REQUEST array does not contain the desired key even though I seemed to have entered the right settings in my HTML form as well as in my JS.

I apologize if the mistake might seem silly but I am new to PHP hence why the confusion.

// PHP //

```
<?php

//var_dump($_REQUEST);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$url =
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' .
    $_REQUEST['latitude'] .
    '&lon=' .
    $_REQUEST['longitude'] .
    '&appid=mykey';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
//$encode = json_encode($data);
$decode = json_decode($data, true);
//echo($_REQUEST);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

?>


/// JS/JQUERY


        $.ajax({
            url: "../project1/php/weather.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                latitude: $('#latitude').val(),
                longitude: $('#longitude').val()
            },
            success: function (result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                if (result) {

                    // to be updated

                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
            }
        });


    }).addTo(map);



/// HTML//

.....

<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="latitude" id="latitude" step="0.01"/>
        <input type="number" name="longitude" id="longitude" step="0.01"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="globeBig.png" class="logo"/>
        <h1>The Gazetteer</h1>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>Country Information</li>
            <li>Weather</li>
            <li>Earthquakes</li>
            <li>
                <select class="country"></select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

....

Comment: Do you prevent the page from reloading? Something like `$('form').on('submit', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); // then the ajax call... ` - And is `../project1/php/weather.php` a separate file than the one having the HTML and JS/jQuery code?

Comment: Hi Patrice, If I add that function my easybutton disappears( I am working on a leaflet.js map project) hence not allowing me to fetch the information.

Comment: Your PHP isn't checking to see if data has been submitted. When you open the page it just goes straight to make the cURL call and won't yet have any data.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular thanks for the hint, any suggestions on how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax requests to load additionnal info has to be done from client-side to server-side where an eventual result of the server-side processing will be used to update the initial page on the client-side.

So you need two files... Let's say `index.php` and `weather.php`.

First load `index.php` in a browser... Interact with the page in order to send an ajax request to `weather.php`.
Then the response has to be handled by that initial load of `index.php`.

The error you are making is the page squarely reloads WHILE the ajax request is sent out (if ever sent... in which case the response will end in nothingness).

Try that out!

### Index:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- stuff here-->
    <!-- like jQuery lib -->
  </head>
  <body>
      <form method="POST">
          <input type="number" name="latitude" id="latitude" step="0.01"/>
          <input type="number" name="longitude" id="longitude" step="0.01"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
      <nav class="navbar">
          <img src="globeBig.png" class="logo"/>
          <h1>The Gazetteer</h1>
          <ul class="list">
              <li>Country Information</li>
              <li>Weather</li>
              <li>Earthquakes</li>
              <li>
                  <select class="country"></select>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="map"></div>
      
      <script>
        
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      
          $('form').on('submit', function(event){ 
              
              // Will NOT submit the page to allow re ajaxe resquest below
              event.preventDefault()
              
              $.ajax({
                  url: "../project1/php/weather.php",
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                      latitude: $('#latitude').val(),
                      longitude: $('#longitude').val()
                  },
                  success: function (result) {

                      // No need to stringify the result, it already is a JSON string
                      console.log(result);
                      
                      // But you need to parse it
                      const response = JSON.parse(result)

                      if (response && response.success) {

                          // Here, instanciate the leaflet.js map using response.data

                      }
                  },
                  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
                  }
              })
          })
      })
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### weather.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$encode = json_encode('{success: false, data: null}');

// If there are coordinates
if(isset($_REQUEST['latitude']) && isset($_REQUEST['longitude'])){
    $url =
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' .
        $_REQUEST['latitude'] .
        '&lon=' .
        $_REQUEST['longitude'] .
        '&appid=mykey';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    
    $encode = json_encode('{success: true, data: ' . $data . '}');
}

// The sent out JSON
echo $encode;
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Louys Patrice Bessette, thank you for your advice. I tried and implement my code as you suggested but it looks as if there is some issue in my server side. I tried to send a post request using postman and it still returned : Warning: Undefined array key "latitude" in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\php\weather.php on line 9

Comment: Since all errors and wrnings are reported, I think using `isset()` to check for the presence of values should fix it. - I edited.